# not defiend global function in ejs template

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i write this helper for using global function :

```
   const path = require('path');
const autuBind = require('auto-bind');

module.exports = class Helpers {

    constructor(req, res) {
        autuBind(this);
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
        this.formData = req.flash('formData')[0];
    }


    getObjects() {
        return {
            auth: this.auth(),
            viewPath: this.viewPath,
            old:this.old,
            ...this.getGlobalVaribales()
        }
    }

    auth() {
        return {
            check: this.req.isAuthenticated(),
            user: this.req.user
        }
    }

    getGlobalVaribales() {
        return {
            errors: this.req.flash('erros')
        }
    }

    viewPath(dir) {
        return path.resolve(config.layout.view_dir + '/' + dir);
    }

    old(field, defaultValue = '') {
        return this.formData && this.formData.hasOwnProperty(field) ? this.formData[field] : defaultValue;
    }


}
```

and set that in the server.js :

```
  app.use((req , res , next) => {
        app.locals = new Helpers(req, res).getObjects();
        next();
    });
```

in use tha tin the `ejs` template :

```
 <input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"  value="<%= old('phoneNumber') %>" required type="text">
```

when use this function : `value="<%= old('phoneNumber') %>"`

it show me this error :

> old is not defined

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: you have to render the values and it is accessible like a JSON format old('phoneNumber') doesnot make sense to EJS

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass data from the template to the server, ejs is a templating language that lets you generate HTML markup it is meant to simplify passing the data to the view using a template that can take javascript.
In your code lets say you want to pass the phone number to the template for example you can do it like this

```
phonenumber= +12345
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{res.render('yourejstemplatename',{number:phonenumber})})
```

and in your template

```
<%if (number!="") {%>

 <input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"  value="<%=number %>" required type="text">
 <%}%>
```